# 6x6 Cedar posts for yard barn, should I glue them?

Tags: glue, shed, barn

I am building a yard barn/shed, that uses cedar posts as the outside framing of the gable ends.

[image: SketchUp model of barn]

I was planning on just drilling and lag-bolting the posts together (plugging the holes) but do you think I should glue them as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gluing won't hurt, but it won't help either (in this application) so I wouldn't bother.

Where gluing does help is when you are doubling a beam by stacking two smaller beams on top of each other. (i.e. 2 2x4's to make a 2x8)  Gluing will then help transfer the longitudinal shear stresses that develop when the beam bends slightly.  (To visualize this shear, bend a paperback book, and see how the pages slide against each other.)

Glue works best to keep things from sliding against each other. It's worse in a torque scenario, where you would try to twist two pieces apart, and not very good in tension.  It's also completely unnecessary in compression.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that makes sense. My worry is longitudal rafter load in the winter, and wind. It sounds like glue will not add any strength.